# How can I get a running formula with a dynamic range that "starts over" at a certain row condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got running sales numbers, and I'm trying to track win/loss percentage over time to calculate expectancy.

First step was to take the raw data and get a percentage over the number of sales. That was pretty easy with a `COUNTIF`

The problem I'm having is how to have the range for the formula "start over" when the account number changes. I'd prefer to just dump the data into my named table without having to manually reset the formula each time I get a new data dump.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:C2,"Win",$A$2:A2,A2)/B2
```

[image]

Comment: This works as expected. I don't fully understand why, though. It seems as if the second condition the `$A$2:A2` would stop working after the 3rd account because the range row contains the values 1, 2, and now 3. I was trying to solve from the "the account on this row doesn't match the previous row" angle. Than